Kubuntu 24.04 not booting
I've just did a clean install of kubuntu 24.04 on my Ryzen 9 but will not boot after startup.  If do a normal install,  it will reboot only once.  If I do minimal install,  it will not reboot.  Only goes to blank screen with no errors shown.

I'm using an Intel processor. And I had to do a BIOS reset with the hardware jumper to get the system working after the update. Don't know why, but it worked.

I have older Intel chip & installed Kubuntu several times without issue. I like new Calamares installer. What video card/chip? If nVidia are you installing proprietary drivers as part of install? Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

You might want to remove 'quiet splash' from GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT in /etc/defaut/grub and then do a sudo update-grub2. That solves my Kubuntu 24.04 booting problem today.

To dig deeper into the problem:

Boot (after having installed)
Hit ESC once when the UEFI/BIOS text appears
you should get the "grub menu" with an option saying "Advanced options", select it
in the advanced options menu you will see one option stating "Recover mode", again select it
you will get a text mode menu with "fsck", "networking" and "drop to root prompt" - select those in that order.
hit Enter once to actually get a bash prompt as root user -> # and a blinking cursor.

... you now have access to the linux installation as the root user.
# dmesg | less (hit Enter!) - will show one of the log files created as you start the computer. ESC to exit less, i.e. get back to the prompt.
Many more log files exist, check
cd /var/log  
ls -l  

Where
less filename
Will show the content of the ones not having *.gz in the filename; use
zcat filename | less
for those
One more thing: less has a lot of options, as you have done one of the things above, ending in less, hit h to display the help (and again ESC to exit from there).
In there you will find among other things / for searching...
use it to look for 'error', 'failed', 'skipped' and such in the log files.
Now, with the above knowledge, look around in the files, and add any suspect information to your posting above.
